# commandLink only works with a h and p version

Tags: jsf, glassfish-4, commandlink

I'm having this really weird issue where my `commandLink`only work if I have BOTH links in the same view.

Works fine, both links:

```
<ui:composition template="../../template.xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
            xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable var="v" value="#{myBean.myList}">
                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <h:commandLink value="Go to next page" action="#{myBean.doThing(v)}" />
                    <p:commandLink value="Go to next page" action="#{myBean.doThing(v)}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{myBean.submit}" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

But if I remove either link, it doesn't even reach the method `doThing()` and reloads an empty page.

My bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {
    private List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    public MyBean() {
    }

    public String doThing(Object obj) {
        // This never prints if I remove one of the links
        System.out.println("You're doing the thing!");
        return "nextView?faces-redirect=true"
    }

    // Getters, setters etc.
}
```

I'm using JSF 2.0 and GlassFish 4.0.

How can I fix this and why is it happening?

I have a `commandLink` in a `p:dataTable` in another view and it's working fine.

#### EDIT:

Added the complete XML for the composition part of the view. The partial is inside a template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <!-- css imports, titles etc -->
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:insert name="menu">
            <ui:include src="./default/content.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add full xhtml page.

Comment: You want the template XML as well?

Comment: Please check if your page contain  `h:form` or not ? and these button inside the  `h:form` or not ? Also there should not be nested `h:form`

Comment: It is in a h:form, else it wouldn't work at all with both links. Sorry that I forgot to add it to my question.

Comment: Please add your xhtml full page

Comment: THis is your full Xhtml ? Did u confirmed no nested h:form ?

Comment: I have Imports as well. No nested h:form but there are commandbuttons in the view.

Comment: I've downgraded to gf 4.0 because of bugs in the newest version

Comment: Updated with all the xml now, including the template that it's in and the `commandButton` for the form.